# Tokenizer with Pygments in Python

Tags: python, tokenize, pygments

Want to create a tokenizer for source files (e.g. Java or C++) in Python. Came across [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) and in particular these [lexers](http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/#lexers-for-c-c-languages). I could not found examples i the [documentation](http://pygments.org/docs/quickstart/) and online for how to use the lexer.

Wondering if it is possible to actually use Pygments in Python in order **to get the tokens and their position** for a given source file.

I am struggling with the very basics here, so If someone could offer even a small chunk of code detailing the above it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the source of Pygment's [`highlight`](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/src/ef81d4814bc6b6894cc054b3b66bb2dcbf79add9/pygments/__init__.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#__init__.py-77) function, essentially what it does is pass the source text into a lexer instance via the [`get_tokens`](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/src/ef81d4814bc6b6894cc054b3b66bb2dcbf79add9/pygments/lexer.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#lexer.py-139) method, which returns a list of tokens. Those tokens are then passed to the formatter. As you want the list of tokens, without the formatter, you only need to do the first part.

So to use the C++ lexer (where `src` is a string containing your C++ source code):

```
from pygments.lexers.c_cpp import CppLexer

lexer = CppLexer()
tokens = lexer.get_tokens(src)
```

Of course, you could [lookup](http://pygments.org/docs/quickstart/#lexer-and-formatter-lookup) or [guess](http://pygments.org/docs/quickstart/#guessing-lexers) the lexer instead of importing the desired lexer directly by using one of `get_lexer_by_name`, `get_lexer_for_filename`, `get_lexer_for_mimetype`, `guess_lexer`, or `guess_lexer_for_filename`. For example:

```
from pygments.lexers import get_lexer_by_name

Lexer = get_lexer_by_name('c++')
lexer = Lexer()  # Don't forget to create an instance
tokens = lexer.get_tokens(src)
```

Whether the returned list of tokens will provide you with what you want it another matter. You'll have to try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the `tokenize` module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/tokenize.html if you are going to tokenize Python code. Otherwise PyParsing creates lexers that are easy to understand...

Comment: I want to tokenize c++ source in Python (so the `tokenize` module you mention is not good for me) and I was hoping that Pygments did not merely provided highlighting but also could give tokenization abilities (get tokens and their positions). So, was I wrong to think that Pygments could be used for that?

Comment: Parsing, and even tokenizing, c++ is notoriously hard. I would suggest using CastXML (https://github.com/CastXML/CastXML) to generate xml that your Python program can consume.  If your use-case is very trivial then perhaps Pygments can help you...

Comment: My use-case is indeed trivial (or at least I believe it is); i.e. I only want to tokenize vairable definitions, function definitions, keywords etc. Do you have any idea how I could do that with Pygments or any other tool? (I only focused on Pygments because I saw that it could handle c++ source easily for what I was looking for)

Comment: Sorry, it's been a long while since I used Pygments, but the source is pretty readable.